# "register" a unit and prefix with sympy?

Tags: python, sympy, dimension, units-of-measurement

```
import sympy.physics.units as u
u.find_unit('cm')  # -->  'cm' found
u.find_unit('km')  # -->  'km' found

# so I can do
float(u.convert_to(2 * u.cm, u.km) / u.km)
```

Now I would like to register `nF` (nano-farads), `pF` (pico-farads), and `uF` (micro-farads)
so I can do quick conversions like this (and in other complex calculations):

```
float(u.convert_to(2 * u.uF, u.nF) / u.nF)
```

One idea I have is to do this:

```
u.uF = 1e-6 * u.F
u.nF = 1e-9 * u.F
float(u.convert_to(36 * u.uF, u.nF) / u.nF)
```

Is there any harm in this? One issue I see is that if I keep the unit, it will only be represented in the base (F). Also I'd need to check to ensure I'm not overwriting any attibutes of `u`. Further, `u.find_unit("nF")` returns a blank list.

There aren't many good references on how to apply prefixes in our units.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in sympy.physics.units.definitions.unit_definitions.py you will see examples of how to set definitions like

```
mg = milligram = milligrams = Quantity("milligram", abbrev="mg")
mg.set_global_relative_scale_factor(milli, gram)
```

So

```
>>> from sympy.physics.units import *
>>> nf=Quantity('nanoFarad', abbrev='nF')
>>> nf.set_global_relative_scale_factor(nano, farad)
>>> nf
nF
>>> nf.convert_to(farad)
F/1000000000
```

Comment: for units like Fahrenheit the unit conversion isn't a simple multiple. How will we forth defining F

Comment: There is discussion of temperatures at https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/21628

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a sympy expert, but I think the following way might be more robust ([see this](https://github.com/hgrecco/pint/issues/606#issuecomment-1771719687)):

```
>>> import sympy.physics.units as syu
>>> setattr(syu, 'nanoFarad', syu.Quantity('nanoFarad', abbrev='nF', is_prefixed=True))
>>> setattr(syu, 'nF', getattr(syu, 'nanoFarad'))
>>> getattr(syu, 'nanoFarad').set_global_relative_scale_factor(syu.nano, syu.farad)
>>> syu.nF.convert_to(syu.F)
farad/1000000000
```

Another example:

```
>>> setattr(syu, 'kilogramforce', syu.Quantity('kilogramforce', abbrev='kgf', is_prefixed=True))
>>> setattr(syu, 'kgf', getattr(syu, 'kilogramforce'))
>>> getattr(syu, 'kilogramforce').set_global_relative_scale_factor(9.80665, syu.newton)
>>>
>>> syu.kgf.convert_to(syu.N)
9.80665*newton
```

For some units `is_prefixed` (`True` when prefix is 'milli-','kilo-', etc.) shall be set to `False`.